# Atom Editor on Yosemite unable to 'git pull'

Tags: macos, editor, beta, atom-editor

when issuing a 'git pull' from atom editor i get the following error

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-pull: line 11: git-sh-setup: No such file or directory
```

this has been ongoing for me since DP2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OSX 10.10 yosemite beta on git pull: git-sh-setup: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022582/osx-10-10-yosemite-beta-on-git-pull-git-sh-setup-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Looks like it's affecting other editors as well: https://github.com/SublimeGit/SublimeGit/issues/150